# Package functions not loaded after successful `Get` (`<<`)

Tags: programming, function-construction, packages, databaselink

I have the following package:

```
(* Wolfram Language Package *)

(* Created by the Wolfram Workbench Aug 13, 2015 *)

BeginPackage["XxDataLink`",{"DatabaseLink`"}]
(* Exported symbols added here with SymbolName::usage *) 

OpenXxSQLConnection::usage="Open the connection to the Xx database."
CloseXxSQLConnection::usage="Closes the connection to the Xx database."

Begin["`Private`"]
(* Implementation of the package *)
XxSQLConnection;

OpenXxSQLConnection[]:=
 Module[{},
  If[! SQLConnectionUsableQ[XxSQLConnection],
   XxSQLConnection = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", "server"], "Catalog" -> "Xx"];
  ];
  XxSQLConnection
 ]

CloseXxSQLConnection[]:=
 CloseSQLConnection[XxSQLConnection]


End[]

EndPackage[]
```

This is installed to the `$BaseDirectory` in an XxDataLink directory.  There is a sub directory called Kernel with an *init.m* file with the following line `` Get[ "XxDataLink`XxDataLink`"] ``.

In a new instance of Mathematica I do a `Get` (`<<`) on this package and try to open the database connection (no error messages).

```
<< "XxDataLink`"
conn = OpenXxSQLConnection[]
(* OpenXxSQLConnection[] *)
```

What am I doing wrong?  I am expecting to get a connection to the database.  I've added the jTDS DLL file so that can use SQL Server integrated security for the connection and the code works outside of the package.

```
OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", "server"], "Catalog" -> "Xx"]
{SQLConnectionUsableQ[#], SQLConnectionOpenQ[#]} &[%]
(* {True, True} *)
```

Returns an open usable connection when run directly in a notebook.  Not certain why I'm not getting one when I run it through the package.  The package and `DatabaseLink` are loading with the `Get` as I can run `OpenSQLConnection` after I load `XxDataLink` without explicitly loading `DatabaseLink` in the notebook.

Mathematica 10.1 and Windows 7

### **Update:**

Also tried in 10.2 and Windows 7 with the same results.  Can anyone repeat this behavior? Could it be some sort of bug with the Mathematica `DatabaseLink` package? I'm thinking it wouldn't be since tons of people must have done this before me and had it work.

Comment: It might be that SQLConnectionUsableQ yields a definite a true or False only when given a real connection link as parameter. It might return unevaluated when not, causing the If branch to return unevaluated.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Nope.  It returns false when not given connection.  Tried that before I made function in the package.  I just tested again to be certain with `SQLConnectionUsableQ[x]` returns `(* Flase *)` for uninitialised `x`.

Comment: Is `XxDataLink` directory directly inside `$BaseDirectory`? Are you sure you have `$BaseDirectory` in your `$Path`, by default it's not. But if it's not, then you should get `Get::noopen` message, so there must be something else wrong. What does ``FindFile["XxDataLink`"]`` return?

Comment: @jkuczm Yes, `$BaseDirectory` is in `$Path`. `XxDataLink.m` is in *XxDataLink* directory in `$BaseDirectory`. The *XxDataLink* directory has the *Kernel* subdirectory. ``FindFile["XxDataLink`"]`` returns the *init.m* filename ( C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Applications\XxDataLink\Kernel\init.m ).

Comment: I just reproduced your package setup and everything "works", i.e. after getting the package and calling `OpenXxSQLConnection[]` I get `JDBC::error: Unknown server host name 'server'.` `$Failed`. I'm using v10.2 on Linux.

Comment: Is `OpenXxSQLConnection` symbol blue or black after loading the package? What does `?? OpenXxSQLConnection` return? Can you add something like `Print["I was loaded."]` at the end of package file? Is this text printed when loading the package?

Comment: @jkuczm `??OpenXxSQLConnection` returns the `usage` message. The `Print` does show in the notebook when I load the package. `OpenXxSQLConnection` is black when I type it it after loading the package.  All of this in a new instance of Mathematica.

Comment: "`??OpenXxSQLConnection` returns the usage message." Only usage message, or usage message together with proper definition?

Comment: @jkuczm Only the usage message. Should it be returning more for `??`?

Comment: Single `?` returns only usage message, double `??` should return usage message and definition, in this case I get whole `OpenXxSQLConnection[] := blah blah` printed after the usage message.

Comment: @jkuczm I tried deleting the directory, restarting Mathematica, tried to load the package then exited.  Then created the directories and files, then started Mathematica, and loaded the package. Same results. Functions not loaded and only usage message with `??`.  Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Maybe you have some typo in your package, that you accidentally corrected when posting code in your question? Try copying the code from your post and paste it to your package, that's what I did and package worked.

Comment: @jkuczm Oh, for the love of Zeus!!! What I wouldn't give for some peer review in times like these. The gruesome pain has come to a close. It was a **f**orsaken typo (and that f is well placed).

Comment: It happens to the best of us ;)

Comment: @jkuczm That's a heckuva guess!

Comment: @MichaelE2 As can be seen above, I started with a lot of wrong guesses.

Comment: It was a great help.  Thanks for working through it with me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try

```
If[! TrueQ[SQLConnectionUsableQ[XxSQLConnection]], ...
```

Comment: No dice. Still does not work. I would not have expected that to work since `SQLConnectionUsableQ` returns True or False.

Comment: Maybe if `conn` is defined.  What happens if it isn't defined?

Comment: I'm starting from a fresh loading of Mathematica (only have one instance open) so nothing is previously defined.

Comment: How about `<< "XxDataLink\`XxDataLink\`"` ?  Although it shouldn't be necessary at all if your package is loaded in `init.m`.

Comment: Nope.  That is not doing the trick either.  The package syntax and locations appear correct.  It is very odd.